# Illustrator - Cutting a shape inside a grouped object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a grouped object in illustrator and I want to cut out a circle-shaped hole out of the grouped object. So I draw the circle over the grouped object and:

- If I try to select the grouped object and the circle and go to <kbd>Object > Clipping Mask > Make</kbd>, I get only the small circle as a result (I want the reverse, the big object minus the area of the small circle).
- If I go to <kbd>Window > Pathfinder</kbd>, none of the options has the desired effect -  Pathfinder deletes the components of the grouped object that intersect the small circle, instead of treating the grouped object as a single object

I've made a simple example - the black thing is the grouped object, the red thing is the shape I want to cut out of the grouped object.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to do it in phases in order to get it right. What I did was duplicate the cut out shape for each component. Not ideal, but it works.

Here's what I did from ***within the group***:

## 1) Select the crossing rectangles.

[image]

## 2) Compounded the rectangle shapes to one shape. <kbd>Object > Compound Path > Make</kbd>

[image]

## 3) Duplicate the shape for the cutout and position it over the new compounded shape

[image]

## 4) Select both the cutout and the compound shape and Use the Subtract from shape area button in the `Pathfinder` window <kbd>Window > Pathfinder</kbd>.

[image]

## 5) Hide those for now, and select the other cutout and the base shape

[image]

## 6) Use the Subtract from shape area button in the Pathfinder window.

[image]

## 7) Unhide your crossing rectangles and voila!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you do not need the strokes and shapes in black to remain "live"....

Select the black, `Object > Expand`
Then `Pathfinder > Unite`
Select the new black shape and the red circle, `Pathfinder > Minus Front`

If you *must* keep the black shapes as strokes and live.....

Draw another circle which encompasses all the black.
Place this large circle *behind* the small red circle.
Select the large circle and the small red circle, `Object > Compound Path > Make`
Now select everything and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

[image: duh animashun]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to select only 'Stroke' in the Expand dialog box, or it mangled the black shape when I did Pathfinder>Unite.